# Function for jquery or CSS to dynamically resize an image & text to width and/or height of browser and maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have a div be dynamically resized by browser width and or height and maintain aspect ratio. If possible also have the text inside of the div do the same. Anything would be awesome!

Comment: I understand you need help, but it would be better, if you show your div and what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you're after?

```css
.staticSize {
  border: 3px solid black;
  min-height: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.staticSize * {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="staticSize">
    <h1>
    A heading
    </h1>
    <img src="http://writingexercises.co.uk/images2/randomimage/boat.jpg" width=350/>
    <label>A description of above. Wow, such description. Very descriptive. More text.
    More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 
    More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. </label>
</div>
```

Utilising `min-witdth`, `min-height`, `height` and `width` you can in a way enforce the content remains the same size - however the text inside will still be impacted by browser-driven zoom functionality.

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myLpxnvc/) so you can view the image.

[image: Example]

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for. Just a question though, why do you use the * after referencing the same div on the CSS?

Comment: Oh, that part isn't really essential to how it doesn't resize, I just wanted all the contents in the `div` to be centered. `.staticSize *` just means `all child elements`, so everything within the `div`, i.e. `h1`, `img`, `label` will have the properties as defined in that part of the CSS